# My "rails server" command not working properly and terminating unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever i run my `rails server` command on my command prompt it gives me the following error:

[image]

Since i am new to the Rails, I don't know much about it.
Guide me with the solution if possible..

I am using rails 5 on windows OS

Comment: Please post your error

Comment: Please, post your error. Not a photo of your error. *The error*.

Answer (score 1):

> Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'mysql2' to your Gemfile

As your error says please add `mysql2` in your `Gemfile`

```
# Gemfile
gem 'mysql2'
```

Also make sure you have `mysql` installed

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the error message. You're using mysql2 as your database adaptor, but the gem isn't available. 
add:
`gem 'mysql2'`
to your gemfile, then run `bundle update` from your project folder to install the missing gem.

Comment: The statement " gem 'mysql2' already there in gem file even after that it not working properly

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` or `bundle update` to install the gems? If so, was there an error message returned from that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

> `gem 'mysql'`

in your Gemfile.

If its added then run command `bundle install` to install it. And check whether its installed successfully or not then restart server.

Also check your gem version with your Rails version.